# Nethack build error in MSYS2 mingw32 shell win10 /usr/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: mingw32, msys2, nethack

Trying to compile the NETHACK cloned version 3.6.0 from github in msys2 mingw32 shell under WIN10. I completed the steps
    cd sys/winnt
    call nhsetup.bat
    cd ../../src
then 
    mingw32-make -f Makefile.gcc
fails

```
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Makefile.gcc:834: recipe for target 'o/obj.tag' failed
mingw32-make: *** [o/obj.tag] Error 1
```

$ mingw32-make.exe -v
    GNU Make 4.1.90
    Built for Windows32

$ gcc -v
gcc version 6.2.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project)

Any ideas what it means? Help to track it down would be appreciated!

Comment: I would recommend using `make` (`/usr/bin/make`) instead of `mingw32-make`, but other than that, I don't know what the problem might be. If you could link to the source code you tried to compile then someone might be able to reproduce the problem and help you.

Comment: Code come from here.
    $ git remote -v
    origin  https://github.com/NetHack/NetHack.git (fetch) 
    origin  https://github.com/NetHack/NetHack.git (push)
 /usr/bin/make has the same result